# What is this electronic component, in series (I think) with the fuse just on the input of a computer PSU?

Tags: power-supply, identification, components

Is similar tu a capacitor but is in series, the neutral cable of the phase is conected direct to this.. or I think is maybe after it passes the fuse...

On the board it is writen THR and on another board it says TH3...

What it is?

Some low voltage power made this to blow

Here ar some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the image inline in the post, that way if/when the image is no longer available on ibb.co it will still be available here.

Comment: Done. Added the photos so they never get lost.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely an inrush limiting NTC thermistor.

Here's a picture of one from Amphenol:

[image]

When you turn the device on the thermistor is presumably cold, and has a higher resistance.  It therefore limits the current (most likely that current is charging big capacitors) and reduces the chance of blowing breakers or fuses.

Once the device has heated up, the resistance drops to the point where it doesn't affect circuit operation, or the losses incurred are acceptable.

Of course if you cycle power on and off quickly when the device is hot, there could be a problem.

Not sure what "low power electricity" is in your context.  If there was just enough current to keep the device in a high dissipation state it could conceivably blow, but without more detail it's hard to say.

It's also possible that there's something downstream that has soft failed, and the thermistor blows due to the increased load.  (Which isn't quite enough to blow the fuse.)

Comment: Probably OP means a "brownout", which would cause a SWPS to draw higher than normal current, possibly leading to an early demise for the NTC inrush  limiting thermistor (THR). By the way, it occurs to me that future generations may be puzzled by the term "brownout", which come from the reddening of the light from incandescent bulbs operated at lower than normal voltage, cp. with "blackout". LED bulbs don't do that, of course.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ah, that makes sense, I hadn't thought of that.  Good point about the "brownout" too.  I'm constantly surprised by what some of the young people at work have no experience of.  Recently one of them was completely surprised that there was a time when TV was only in black and white.

Comment: Wondefull answer.. I mean low voltage, probably made to increase current, or even better, as you said.. something downstream was creating abnormally high load (some 3 or 4 parallel fans wrongly (risky) connected to the +5 and +12 lines. 5v is not designed to take or sing current).  Thank you.